# guard and pure in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was reading [Dynamic programming example](https://wiki.haskell.org/Dynamic_programming_example), there is a code like this:

```
buy n = r!n
    where r = listArray (0,n) (Just (0,0,0) : map f [1..n])
          f i = do (x,y,z) <- attempt (i-6)
                   return (x+1,y,z)
                `mplus`
                do (x,y,z) <- attempt (i-9)
                   return (x,y+1,z)
                `mplus`
                do (x,y,z) <- attempt (i-20)
                   return (x,y,z+1)
          attempt x = guard (x>=0) >> r!x
```

My question is how the `attempt x = guard (x>=0) >> r!x` works?

According to this [Control.Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#guard) source code,

```
guard True      =  pure ()
guard False     =  empty

pure :: a -> f a

m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
```

so if x>0, then:

```
attempt x
    = (guard True) >> (r!x) = (pure ()) >> (r!x)
    = (pure ()) >>= \_ -> r!x = (f ()) >>= (\_ -> r!x)
```

hence `f ()` should be of type `m a` (`Maybe a` in this case), but how does Haskell know what `f` is? `f ()` may return `empty` since it has never been specified. (`f` means `f` in pure)

And if x<0, `empty` is not in `Maybe`, how can this still applied to `>>=`?

Comment: `pure () :: Maybe () == Just ()`?

Comment: @Mephy  How does `Maybe () == Just ()` applied to `>>=`?

Comment: There is no application, `pure () :: Maybe ()` is defined as `Just ()`, in the line 634 of [this source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last expression of your manual evaluation of `attempt x` you are mixing up types and values. `pure :: a -> f a` is not a definition; it is a type signature (note the `::`). To quote it fully, the *type* of `pure` is:

```
GHCi> :t pure
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
```

Here, the `f` stands for any instance of `Applicative`, and the `a` for any type. In your case, you are working with the `Maybe` monad/applicative functor, and so `f` is `Maybe`. The type of `pure ()` is `Maybe ()`. (`() :: ()` is a dummy value used when you are not interested in a result. The `()` in `pure ()` is a value, but the `()` in `Maybe ()` is a type -- the type of the `()` value).

We will continue from the last correct step in your evaluation:

```
(pure ()) >>= \_ -> r!x
```

> how does Haskell know what [`pure ()`] is?

In a sense, it doesn't need to. The function which makes use of `pure ()` here is `(>>=)`. It has the following type:

```
GHCi> :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Setting `m` to `Maybe`, as in your case,  we get:

```
Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
```

The type of the first argument is `Maybe a`, and so `(>>=)` is able to handle any `Maybe a` value, including `pure ()`, regardless of whether it is a `Just`-something or `Nothing`. Naturally, it will handle `Just` and `Nothing` *differently*, as that is the whole point of [the `Monad` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-642):

```
(Just x) >>= k      = k x
Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
```

We still have to complete the evaluation. To do so, we need to know how `pure` is defined for `Maybe`. We can find the definition in [the `Applicative` instance of `Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-633):

```
pure = Just
```

Now we can finally continue:

```
(pure ()) >>= \_ -> r!x
Just () >>= \_ -> r!x
(\_ -> r!x) () -- See the implementation of `(>>=)` above.
r!x
```

Answer (score 3):

That's multiple questions in one, but let's see if I can make things a bit more clear.

How does Haskell know what `f` is when interpreting `pure ()`?  `pure` is a typeclass method, so this simply comes from the instance declaration of the type we're in.  This changed recently, so you may have to follow a different path to reach the answer, but the result ends up the same: [`pure` for `Maybe` is defined as `Just`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-633).

In the same way, [`empty` *is* in `Maybe`, and is defined as `Nothing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-685).

You'll find out what typeclass provides those functions by typing `:i pure` or `:i empty` at a ghci prompt; then you can seek the instance declaration `Maybe` makes for them.

It is unfortunate from an SO point of view that this changed recently so there's no clear permanent answer without knowing the specific versions you're using. Hopefully this will settle soon.

Comment: This solves my question, but I found a new question in the code, how does `(x,y,z) <- attempt (i-6)` work? `(x,y,z)` is a tuple but `attempt x` is `Just a` or `Nothing`, it would be extremely appreciated if you could answer again.

Comment: @CYC That is how `do` blocks work. [Here is an explanation of them](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation).